# RKResponseMapperOperation.m:363 Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'text/html'

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

1) Since im a beginner in programming i cant really debug as to what the problem is; if the problem is with parsing how am i supposed to do it with restkit?
2) I've spent 2 days searching for some direction which could help me sign up a user with a server by doing a post call. please ignore any obvious mistakes as you too may have just started with programming once in your life.

//// here is my code :

```
 -(void)makePostCallToServer
{ 
NSURL *baseeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:baseURL];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseeURL];

// initialize RestKit
objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

// SEEKER MAPPING
RKObjectMapping *seekerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SeekerData class]];
[seekerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                    @"status": @"status"}];
 // USER MAPPING . OBJECT IS INSIDE SEEKER
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserData class]];
[seekerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"userName", @"password", @"userType", @"emailId", @"mobileNumber", @"firstName",@"lastName",@"profilePicUrl",@"Location"]];
 // DEFINING THE RELATIONSHIP MAPPING
[seekerMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"userData"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"data"
                                                                             withMapping:userMapping]];



   RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:seekerMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                        pathPattern:@"api/Seekers" // switch with nil and check
                                            keyPath:@"Seekers"
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
  ////////////////// response descriptor
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];



 // added afterwards
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/html"];

 //// request mapping
    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"status", @"userData"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor =
[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[SeekerData class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];








 RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:user1
                                                                                          method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                            path:@"api/Seekers"
                                                                                      parameters:nil];
operation.targetObject = nil;

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operation, RKMappingResult * mappingResult)
  {
     SeekerData * logInUser = [SeekerData new];

     logInUser = mappingResult.firstObject;


     //         if([logInUser.VolunteerID isEqualToString:Nil])
     //         {
     //             NSLog(@"Not Registered");
     //         }

  }
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError * error) {
     RKLogError(@"Operation failed with eeeerrrrror: %@", error);
        }];
[operation start];



      }
```

Comment: is the server intended to be returning html? is the problem that it returns html at all, or that you need to teach it to treat html as json (which i see you've looked at doing)? show an example of the good response json and headers. I suspect your `operation` setup is wrong so you're sending an invalid request...

Comment: well.. anything scary regarding networking and i see Wain to the rescue everywhere :p the server only intends to return json. is it wrong the way im doing it? i added text/html in hope to remove one of the errors in the console which i did by adding that line...

Comment: P.S : im a total newb just started to work at back-end after almost mastering ui/ux ... back-end is the real deal anyway..

Comment: based on the code i guess you're supplying a `UserData` class to a request where you only have a mapping for  `SeekerData` so the request is malformed and the server is returning an html error page...

Comment: im desperate as i have to implement 81 calls and i just cudnt figure out the first one. once i understand whats going on i will be able to with the help of God :) if i send u the server url cud u see how a simple post call can ACTUALLY post data to it? ive tried multiple ways ; AFNetworking, RestKit and simple post call

Comment: use charles proxy to check what you're actually sending and add that and what you want to send to the question

Comment: THERE IS NO GOOD TUTORIAL for someone who has just stepped into the web services world in iOS :( some old ones are there with deprecated methods

Comment: the server is expecting what im sending. its a nested class        interface SeekerData : NSObject
property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *status;
property (nonatomic) UserData* userData;
end

Comment: if the server is getting what it expects it should be returning json to you, unless it's broken - you should check with charles proxy to be sure what's going on

Comment: on to charles proxy! thankyou for a direction!!

Comment: ok charles is showing me nice info here, a bit overwhelming for me

Comment: REQUEST : POST /Help/api/Seekers HTTP/1.1
Host: abode.azurewebsites.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html
User-Agent: Hong Kong Service Application/1 (iPhone; iOS 9.1; Scale/2.00)
Accept-Language: en-US;q=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 57

status=wattup&userData=%3CUserData%3A%200x7fc93bcb9450%3E

Comment: RESPONSE : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 295
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=249b5a10d50d1612f9b83f264281c47244fc4081c9452afa14b8d847b88bb5d8;Path=/;Domain=abode.azurewebsites.net
Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2015 13:40:33 GMT

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Error.</h1>
        <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
    </hgroup>
</body>
</html>

Comment: do you intend to be sending and receiving json? you are actually sending form encoded and asking to receive html...

Comment: yes..did u get wat im doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main problem is that you haven't set the default request mime type to be JSON. The default is form url encoded and you can see that's what you're getting in the request. You need to remove the html response type you've added to try to deal with the current situation.